# Stretch layout to screen

Tags: android

I have the following layout. I'm using layout_weight="1", so that everything will stretch to fit the screen uniformly. The user has the option to delete images, by basically setting visibility="gone".

Let's say the user deletes both images in the middle LinearLayout, I want that layout to disappear. Currently, if you delete both images the empty layout stays there leaving a gap. How might I get this to work properly so that the other layouts fill in the empty space?

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:width="fill_parent" android:height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">
      <Image></Image>
      <Image></Image>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">
      <Image></Image>
      <Image></Image>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">
      <Image></Image>
      <Image></Image>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do this in Java code.   In code set the LinearLayout (which is a subclass of View) to be invisible.

```
LinearLayout layout1 = this.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
//Some logic here to determine if the images in that layout have been removed or not
//if they gone then..
layout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Something like that.  You'll also probably want to see if this expands the existing layouts to take up the void it left.  I haven't tested this but I'm guessing this may solve your solution?  :-)